# is there a mysqldump option for "Maximal length of created query" which I noticed in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I am getting server has gone away errors when i try to re import a database created with mysqldump. I don't get that error when I export from phpmyadmin. I am trying to mimic the phpmyadmin export output with mysqldump.

phpmyadmin has something called "Maximal length of created query" set to 50000. What option does that translate to in the mysqldump command?

Here is what I have so far:

`mysqldump -u username -p pass > backup.sql`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will limit the length of the generated queries.

`--net-buffer-length 5000`